# sql query: how to make the parents without children?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I have this query to get the first result I want from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941145/sql-query-how-to-make-the-tags-without-children-to-become-parents) earlier,

```
SELECT parents.tag_id AS ParentID,
       parents.tag_name AS ParentName,
       COUNT(childs.tag_id) AS TotalChildren
FROM root_tags AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_tags AS childs
        ON parents.tag_id = childs.parent_id
WHERE parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
ORDER BY parents.tag_id
```

Which returns,

```
ParentID    ParentName  TotalChildren
3           Tagname-1   2
5           tagname-2   2
6           tagname-3   1
9           tagname-4   1
18          tagname-10  0
24          tagname-13  0
26          tagname-14  0
28          tagname-15  0
```

But I have another problem now as I want to return the parents that have not children at all,

```
ParentID    ParentName  TotalChildren
18          tagname-10  0
24          tagname-13  0
26          tagname-14  0
28          tagname-15  0
```

So I tried to make query into this,

```
SELECT 
    parents.tag_id AS ParentID,
    parents.tag_name AS ParentName,
    COUNT(childs.tag_id) AS TotalChildren

FROM root_tags AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_tags AS childs
    ON parents.tag_id = childs.parent_id

WHERE parents.parent_id IS NULL
AND COUNT(childs.tag_id) = '0'
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
ORDER BY parents.tag_id
```

But it returns an error `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `HAVING` clause to you original query:

```
SELECT parents.tag_id AS ParentID,
       parents.tag_name AS ParentName,
       COUNT(childs.tag_id) AS TotalChildren
FROM root_tags AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_tags AS childs
        ON parents.tag_id = childs.parent_id
WHERE parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
HAVING COUNT(childs.tag_id) = 0
ORDER BY parents.tag_id
```

Your problem is that you tried to use `WHERE` clause with aggregation and function (`COUNT`). But you should use `WHERE` to filter the data *before* aggregation. `HAVING` is for filtering results *after* aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Change this part

```
AND COUNT(childs.tag_id) = '0'
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
```

to

```
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
HAVING COUNT(childs.tag_id) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use HAVING instead of WHERE, and after GROUP BY

http://blog.cnizz.com/tag/mysql-error-1111/

This could be useful.