# sql query: how to filter parent and children tags with a tagged table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, parent-child, tagging

I have a further problem after getting the correct answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941145/sql-query-how-to-make-the-tags-without-children-to-become-parents) - I have to filter the row a bit further which is I have to make sure the tag must be tagged to a page.

This is my `root_mm_tagged_pages table`

```
tag id  pg_id 
3       11  
5       11  
6       11  
18      12  
24      13  
26      13
3       14
```

So I want to return this result,

```
ParentID    ParentName  TotalChildren   TotalTagged
3           Tagname-1   2               2
5           tagname-2   2               1
6           tagname-3   1               1
18          tagname-10  0               1
24          tagname-13  0               1
26          tagname-14  0               1
```

I tried with this query but I get an error - `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COUNT( tagged.pg_id ) AS TotalTagged FROM root_tags AS parents LEFT OUTER JOI' at line 5` ,

```
SELECT 
    parents.tag_id AS ParentID,
    parents.tag_name AS ParentName,
    COUNT(childs.tag_id) AS TotalChildren
    COUNT( tagged.pg_id ) AS TotalTagged

FROM root_tags AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_tags AS childs
    ON parents.tag_id = childs.parent_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_mm_tagged_pages AS tagged
    ON tagged.tag_id = parents.tag_id

WHERE parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
ORDER BY parents.tag_id
```

How can I fix it and filter the result further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing comma after `TotalChildren` alias.

```
SELECT 
    parents.tag_id AS ParentID,
    parents.tag_name AS ParentName,
    COUNT(childs.tag_id) AS TotalChildren , --You missed the comma here
    COUNT( tagged.pg_id ) AS TotalTagged
FROM root_tags AS parents
    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_tags AS childs
    ON parents.tag_id = childs.parent_id

    LEFT OUTER JOIN root_mm_tagged_pages AS tagged
    ON tagged.tag_id = parents.tag_id

WHERE parents.parent_id IS NULL
GROUP BY parents.tag_id, parents.tag_name
ORDER BY parents.tag_id
```

Comment: @lauthiamkok: In the 1 year you've been here, you've posted 212 questions -- often several in a day -- most of which are just about finding silly typos like this for you. Can I suggest increasing the time spent debugging your code, before resorting to asking others for help? This stuff is trivial! :)